# Nuget - How to specify/control deeper dependencies in your Nuspec?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuspec

This may be a non-question, but maybe there's a way?

If in my package nuspec i specify : `<dependency id="ServiceStack" version="[3.9.71]"/>`

When i install this package in a project, nuget will rightly attempt to install ServiceStack, along with ALL of it's dependencies... most of which i know are not needed by this package. Ex. ServiceStack.OrmLite

So is there a way to specify my nuspec dependency such that nuget installs only the single package and not the entire graph. Similar to if i had written :

`Install-Package ServiceStack -IgnoreDependencies -Version 3.9.71`

The only solution i know of at the moment is to include the necessary servicestack DLLs i need directly as lib in my package instead of specifying the package as a dependency, which i'd rather avoid...

Comment: Try specifying `developmentDependency="true"` in your dependency.

Comment: I can try that... but i believe it excludes the dependency entirely. I want it included but to ignore deeper dependencies it may have.